# C: Passing pointers to a recursive function

Tags: c, recursion

So I'm struggling on a recursive function to enter a directory and it's subdirectories to save all the file names and a counter for the number of files. I don't know if this is the best way to save the file names, but I don't see any other way. I'm having problems passing the array of pointers and the file counter to the function.

Sorry for any absurd code.

Here's what I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char * path = argv[1];
    char ** tempFiles = NULL;
    int fileCounter = 0;

    findFilesRecursive(&fileCounter, &tempFiles, path);

    for (int i = 0; i < fileCounter; i++)
        printf("\n[%d]: %s", i, tempFiles[i]);
}


void findFilesRecursive(int * fileCounter, char ** tempFiles, char * path) {
    DIR * dirStream;
    struct dirent * entry;

    if(!(dirStream = opendir(path)))
        return;

    while ((entry = readdir(dirStream)) != NULL) {
        if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR) {
            if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") == 0)
                continue;

            char fullPath[strlen(path) + strlen(entry->d_name) + 1];
            sprintf(fullPath, "%s%s/", path, entry->d_name);

            findFilesRecursive(&(*fileCounter), &tempFiles, fullPath);
        } else if (entry->d_type == DT_REG) {

            char filePath[strlen(path) + strlen(entry->d_name)];
            sprintf(filePath, "%s%s", path, entry->d_name);

            printf("FILE: %s\n", filePath);

            tempFiles = (char **) realloc(tempFiles, (*fileCounter + 1) * sizeof(char *));
            tempFiles[*fileCounter] = (char *) MALLOC(strlen(filePath) * sizeof(char));
            strcpy(tempFiles[*fileCounter], filePath);
            (*fileCounter)++;

        }
    }
    closedir(dirStream);
}
```

Comment: You may define a new counter variable in the  `if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR) {` and pass a pointer to it, instead of a shared variable. That way you don't need to rely on it to be initialised properly. And to avoid too many reallocs you could have created a structure that holds a pointer to a pointer to a char and additional fields that could hold say current capacity and number of elements in a collection.

Comment: You never initialize `tempFiles` to any sane value. You pass its address to `findFilesRecursive`, and then pass that address to `realloc`. That doesn't make any sense -- you can only use `realloc` to either get a brand new block (in which case, you must pass it `NULL`) or to enlarge an existing block you got from `malloc` or `realloc`.

Comment: I'm sorry for the incomplete code, I changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compiler should have warned you that &tempFiles, as in:

findFilesRecursive(&(*fileCounter), &tempFiles, fullPath);

is a char ***, yet you promised the compiler that tempFiles would be a char **.
It is very tempting to be “&” happy in C, but really you should restrict it to an ‘as needed’ basis - it makes the code more understandable.   The construct &(*fileCounter) had me scratching my head, after 30+ years of programming in C.

Comment: I honestly was changing and trying different possibilities, because, as I stated, I'm not very experient in using char ** or char ***, I'm sorry for that. How would I correctly pass tempFiles to the function?

Comment: Just pass tempfiles as is. I think this should work: `findFilesRecursive(fileCounter, tempFiles, fullPath)`. Think like this: my argument `tempFiles` is a `char **` and now i want to give it to a function that expects a `char **`. But `tempFiles`  is a `char **` **already** so i have nothing to do.  Same rationale goes for `fileCounter`.